# Is $\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb{Z})\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R} \simeq\operatorname{Hom}(A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Question is above: Given a ring $A$ (a $\mathbb{Z}$-module) is $\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb{Z})\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R} \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ using the fact that $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}$. If so, does this hold for general rings ($\mathbb{Z}$-modules) $B,C$ instead of $\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{R}$ or even for general $R$-modules $M,N,P$:
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)\otimes_{R}P \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_R(M\otimes_R P,N \otimes_R P)
$$

? (Some sort of distributivity between $\operatorname{Hom}$-functor and Tensor product). If not, are there any constraints on $R,M,N,P$ so that this isomorphism holds?

I tried using the universal property of the tensor product, but I cannot specify those bilinear maps concretely. Maybe that's the case because this equality is wrong. If so, is $\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb{Z})\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R} \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Z})$ or $\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb{Z})\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R} \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb{R})$ correct so that the tensor product is only used on one of the arguments of $\operatorname{Hom}$?

Any help would be appreciated as I'm not too familiar with using the universal property to show isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, with $M,N,P$ being $R$ modules. In what follows, "linear,bilinear", Hom and tensor products all refer to the ring $R$.

The bilinear mapping
\begin{align}
(T,p)\mapsto [m\mapsto T(m)\otimes p] 
\end{align}
from $\text{Hom}(M,N)\times P$ into $\text{Hom}(M, N\otimes P)$ gives rise a unique linear mapping (by the universal property)
\begin{align}
\text{Hom}(M,N)\otimes P \to \text{Hom}(M,N\otimes P) 
\end{align}
such that the appropriate diagram commutes (meaning $T\otimes p$ is mapped to the expression above in square brackets).

If we further assume $M$ is finitely generated and free, then this mapping is even an isomorphism (try proving this). I'm not an algebra wizard, so I'm not sure if/how much we can weaken the assumptions on $M$. In short, tensoring a Hom puts the tensor product in the target space.

If you want to know what happens when the tensor product is in the domain of Hom, then we have (no assumptions needed on $M,N,P$)
\begin{align}
\text{Hom}(M\otimes P,N)\cong \text{Hom}^2(M\times P,N)\cong \text{Hom}\left(M,\text{Hom}(P,N)\right).
\end{align}
The first is by the universal property (a linear mapping out of the tensor product is the same as a bilinear mapping). The next is clear because if $f$ is bilinear we can map it to $m\mapsto f(m,\cdot)$.

By repeatedly the two observations above, we see that if $M_1,M_2,N_1,N_2$ are $R$ modules with $M_1,N_1$ finitely generated and free, then we have
\begin{align}
\text{Hom}(M_1,M_2)\otimes \text{Hom}(N_1,N_2)&\cong
\text{Hom}(M_1\otimes N_1,M_2\otimes N_2)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So it is not possible to get the tensor product into the first argument?

Comment: @LegNaiB I was in the process of updating my answer. It is possible, but it's a different isomorphism.

Comment: I see your edited answer now. The sad thing is, that I already found these three isomorphisms between Hom and tensor product. Is there any possibility to get a statement like it is in my question? A small additional part: What is $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{R})$, I don't know how to compute that?

Comment: @LegNaiB On first glance no, and you can see this quite easily because if we specialize very much to the case when $R$ is a field, and everything is a finite-dimensional vector space, then the dimensions just don't match up (your LHS has dimension $mnp$ while the RHS has dimension $(mp)(np)=mnp^2$, where $m,n,p$ are dimensions of $M,N,P$). For the second question, $\text{Hom}_R(R,M)\cong M$ always. Think about why.

Comment: Okay thanks for the information. I totally forgot about that equality. Is it because we can identify each homomorphism by its value at $f(1)$ and with $(f:1\mapsto m) \mapsto m$ we get an isomorphism?

Comment: @LegNaiB exactly

Comment: One last question, what's about $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$? Is it just $\mathbb{R}$? I don't think so, as the homomorphism depends on more than just the value at $1$.

Comment: @LegNaiB honestly I'm not sure at the moment, because I have the strong urge to say no, but I think I managed to prove that it is true, but at the same time, I'm not that great at algebra so I could very well have made a mistake in my supposed proof. You're better off asking a new question and hopefully someone more knowledgeable can answer

Comment: Thanks, I posted another question.